# How to update a column with concatenate of two other column in a same table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sql-update, string-concatenation

I have a table with 3 columns a, b and c. I want to know how to update the value of third column with concatenate of two other columns in each row.

```
before update
 A    B    c 
-------------
1     4
2     5
3     6

after update
 A    B    c 
-------------
1     4    1_4
2     5    2_5
3     6    3_6
```

How can I do this in oracle?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, you are violating the rules of **normalization**. You must re-think about the design. If you have the values in the table columns, then to get a computed value, all you need is a **select** statement to fetch the result the way you want. Storing computed values is generally a bad idea and considered a bad design.

Anyway,

Since you are on `11g`, If you really want to have a computed column, then I would suggest a **VIRTUAL COLUMN** than manually updating the column. There is a lot of **overhead** involved with an **UPDATE** statement. Using a virtual column would reduce a lot of the overhead. Also, you would completely get rid of the manual effort and those lines of code to do the update. **Oracle does the job for you.**

Of course, you will use the same condition of concatenation in the virtual column clause.

Something like,

`Column_c varchar2(50) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (column_a||'_'||column_b)  VIRTUAL`

**Note :** There are certain restrictions on its use. So please refer the documentation before implementing it. However, for the simple use case provided by OP, a virtual column is a straight fit.

**Update** I did a small test. There were few observations. Please read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28557301/concatenating-numbers-in-virtual-column-expression-throws-ora-12899-value-too-l) for a better understanding about how to implement my suggestion.

Answer (score 16):

Use the concatentation operator `||`:

```
update mytable set
c = a || '_' || b
```

Or better, to avoid having to rerun this whenever rows are inserted or updated:

```
create view myview as
select *, a || '_' || b as c
from mytable
```